# how to filter a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, filter

I have a dictionary made of lists:

```
 dict={name: ['paul', 'eileen', 'carl', 'yuhan'],
       height: [5.11, 5.6, 6.1, 5.9],
       weight: [180, 100, 120, 155],
       age:[59, 12, 44, 21] }
```

from the data in the dictionary I derive another list, for example bmi=calculate_bmi(dict) results in:

```
bmi=[32,20,22,28]
```

Now I want to filter my dictionary according to the array. For example I want to keep only the values corresponding to a bmi>25 so that in the end my dictionary should look like:

```
dict={name: ['paul', 'yuhan'],
      height: [5.11, 5.9],
      weight: [180, 145],
      age:[59,21] }
```

I tried using for and if cycles, but with no success. All the other posts explain how to filter a dictionary based on a key within the dictionary, I could not find how to filter a dictionary based on an external list of values.

Any simple method to achieve this result?

Comment: Seems like a perfect job for a pandas dataframe!

Comment: I cannot use pandas and cannot manipulate the original code that produces the dictionary, any example of how to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you pls post actual Python literals. What is e.g. `name`? Do you mean `"name"`? If so, pls change it.

Comment: You can return another dictionary from your "calculate_bmi()" method with the person's name as its key and actual bmi as its value. After that, you will be able to modify the original dict with using helper dict's values that has matched with original dict's names.

Comment: Your use case is more suitable for a **list of dictionaries** (or maybe a list of objects) instead of a dictionary of lists. Any particular reason you are using a dictionary at the top level?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following which modifies the dict values in-place:

```
bmi = [32,20,22,28]

filtered = lambda v: [x for x, b in zip(v, bmi) if b > 25]
# Or
filtered = lambda v: [x for i, x in enumerate(v) if bmi[i] > 25]

for v in dct.values():
    v[:] = filtered(v)

# {'name': ['paul', 'yuhan'], 'height': [5.11, 5.9], 'weight': [180, 155], 'age': [59, 21]}
```

Or if you prefer a new dict and are into one-liners:

```
out = {k: filtered(v) for k, v in dct.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary comprehension that filters each list by zippping it with the bmi list:

```
d =   {'name': ['paul', 'eileen', 'carl', 'yuhan'],
       'height': [5.11, 5.6, 6.1, 5.9],
       'weight': [180, 100, 120, 155],
       'age':[59, 12, 44, 21] }

bmi=[32,20,22,28]

d = {k:[i for i,b in zip(v,bmi) if b>25] for k,v in d.items()} 

print(d)
{'name': ['paul', 'yuhan'],
 'height': [5.11, 5.9],
 'weight': [180, 155],
 'age': [59, 21]}
```

alternatively, you can build a list of indexes meeting your criteria and use it to access corresponding items within each key's list:

```
idx = [i for i,b in enumerate(bmi) if b>25]
d   = {k:[v[i] for i in idx] for k,v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using some [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)-fu:

```
dic={'name': ['paul', 'eileen', 'carl', 'yuhan'],
     'height': [5.11, 5.6, 6.1, 5.9],
     'weight': [180, 100, 120, 155],
     'age':[59, 12, 44, 21] }
bmi=[32,20,22,28]

out = dict(zip(dic.keys(), zip(*(a for a,b in zip(zip(*dic.values()), bmi) if b>25))))
```

Output:

```
{'name': ('paul', 'yuhan'),
 'height': (5.11, 5.9),
 'weight': (180, 155),
 'age': (59, 21)}
```

With [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

out = pd.DataFrame(dic).loc[np.array(bmi)>25].to_dict('list')
```

Output:

```
{'name': ['paul', 'yuhan'],
 'height': [5.11, 5.9],
 'weight': [180, 155],
 'age': [59, 21]}
```

Comment: That one-liner is way more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: @user2390182 it depends what you mean by "needs to", it's to perform the comparison only once. You can also filter each list independently.

Comment: Not sure that's an improvement. You are now creating a bunch of intermediate `tuples` instead. The nested zipping still means you have to iterate each of them. But instead of doing the comparison multiple times you repackage the list elements multiple times into tuples. The comprehension could also be done without extra-space using enumerate and indexed access into bmi.